# GMAIL API:forward all the client gmail messages to a gmail address by using gmail api

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Currently, I am writing a program to forward all the Gmail messages of users to a Gmail address 
I took the help from:[Link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings)
I created all the storage, credentials file etc 
but when I try to run the program it's giving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hh.py", line 40, in <module>
    thadari()
  File "hh.py", line 30, in thadari
    result = GMAIL.users().settings().forwardingAddresses().create(userId='me', body=address).execute()
  File "/home/vishalthadari/Documents/Seperation 1/virutalenv/python 3/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vishalthadari/Documents/Seperation 1/virutalenv/python 3/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/forwardingAddresses?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

i already gave the sending mail permission to it but I don't know why it's giving the error.there's no scope for forward message as I read here:[link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)
Or do I need to buy google gsuite for this? which is defined here:[Link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)
in gmail.settings.sharing

I know that whole wall of code is not reusable but as I am new to Google API's so I think their's small minor bugs in my code:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient import errors
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import dateutil.parser as parser
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import csv



def thadari():
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
    store = file.Storage('storage.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    user_id = 'me'
    label_id_one = 'INBOX'


    address = {'forwardingEmail': 'girlsdontloveme75@gmail.com'}
    result = GMAIL.users().settings().forwardingAddresses().create(userId='me', body=address).execute()
    if result.get('verificationStatus') == 'accepted':
        body = {
        'emailAddress': result.get('forwardingEmail'),
        'enabled': True,
        'disposition': 'trash'
    }   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thadari()
```

Is this the right way to do it? or there's a better way to do this please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you followed the initial step ([creating a forwarding email address](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses/create))?